# How to square a video in android

Tags: android, video

Recently I made an app that square images so as to be posted correctly on instagram. Well, I was wondering if its possible to square a video too. On my previous app i was squaring a bitmap. It was much easier than videos. Is it possible to show me some tips to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use an Android port of ffmpeg, like this one: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

**ADDED:** ... and surely it will be much harder than just resizing a bitmap. Using ffmpeg needs NDK with some native C code being called from Android Java via JNI.